# Why do I get a 502 when I attempt to access ELB DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I am attempting to host an ASP.NET Core application on an EC2 instance with the following setup (from top to bottom). Given the setup below, I get a health status on the EC2 instance as well as the Target Group. Also, if I check the status of the Kestrel service on the server, I can see incoming requests from the Target Group's health checks with 200 responses.

The problem that I'm having is that if I access the ELB's DNS endpoint, I get a 502 (Bad Gateway) response. Why is this? Especially since I see on the web server the requests for the health checks coming in and met with 200 responses. **I don't however see the requests that I make explicitly against the ELB's DNS endpoint.** It's like the requests to the ELB's DNS endpoint never actually reach the web server.

Another thing that to take not of is that I have a jump server in a public subnet within the same VPC as the private subnet housing the EC2 instance. I am able to make a requests from the jump server to the private IP and get back a 200 response with my login html. It would seem that everything on the web server is correct; something is wrong with something outside of that.

**Route 53**

I'm using a Route 53 hosted zone for my domain. The HZ has an A record that points to a *Elastic Load Balancer*.

**Elastic Load Balancer**

Traffic from the domain (on ports HTTP and HTTPS) gets routed to an *Application Load Balancer* listening to HTTP (80) and HTTPS (443). The HTTPS traffic has a *Certificate Manager*-assigned public SSL cert. The HTTPS traffic terminates here and is passed through to underlying instances as HTTP.

**ELB Target Group**

I have a target group pointing a specified instance. For the target group, I'm targeting the login page of the running application and expecting a 200 response.

**Auto-Scaling Group**

I have an ASG that points to the ELB Target Group.

**Web Server**

For the web server, I'm running an Amazon Linux 2 AMI Instance with Kestrel running behind an Nginx reverse proxy. The Kestrel service hosts an ASP.NET MVC application running on port 5000 (HTTP).

The EC2 instance is sitting in a private subnet. There's a public subnet within the same VPC and AZ with an *Internet Gateway* attached.

For the .NET Core application's *Startup Config*, I am using standard forwarding headers.

There is a Security Group attached to the EC2 instance allowing HTTP and HTTPS traffic from the ELB security group and SSH traffic from a jump box sitting in a public subnet in the same VPC.

Comment: I've made a little progress with this. The issue appears to be on the Kestrel + Nginx side of things (i.e. nothing with the AWS setup). I've done some re-writing of the nginx config files and gotten a little further; now I'm in the process of trying to ensure that the conversation between Kestrel and Nginx goes well, such that Nginx is acting as a reverse proxy whilst keeping the integrity of the traffic down to the HTTP listener in Kestrel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up finding was that my Nginx configuration was conflicting with with the ELB configuration. I ended up restoring the nginx.conf back to its initial state and provided more clearly defined custom configurations under the conf.d folder (I created a .conf file here specifically for my app that routes traffic the way that I want).

I also did the following to streamline my intentions of each pieces' role:

1. Since SSL terminates at the ALB, I modified Kestrel to no longer listen for 443 (HTTPS) traffic; it only listens for 80 (HTTP) traffic. For now, this is fine because there aren't any other members of the VPC which would pose a security threat due to the HTTP traffic past the ELB. Above the ELB, everything is still encrypted.
2. I added an ELB listener that listens for both 443 and 80 traffic and forwards it to a target group which targets 80 only (remember, Kestrel is now only looking for 80 traffic).
3. I also needed to change `startup.cs`to **not** `UseHttpRedirection`; again, SSL terminates at the ELB.

A combination of all of these things resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if its because the header sent to NGINX is too large? You can increase the size allowed in NGINX by changing the following configs.

nginx.conf

```
http{
...
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
...
}
```

default.conf

```
location /{
    ...
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    ...
}
```